# ScalaTest runnning only a single test in a suite

Tags: eclipse, scala, testing, scalatest, scala-ide

While developing a test suite for a class, I've began running into situations where ScalaTest would only run a single test, or exclude some of them.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse was saving different runs of the tests as different run configurations, and depending on how I ran it (usually using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>), it selected specific *tests* in the suite, not the whole suite *class*, and saved those run configurations.

The solution was to delete the new run configurations, and simply right-click the name of the test suite class in the editor, and select *Run as -> ScalaTest - Suite*. More information

Additionally, you can tweak how Eclipse interprets the run command/shortcut, when you go to *Preferences -> Launching*:

[image]

I have selected *Always launch the previously launched application*, and now Eclipse isn't trying to dynamically create run configurations anymore. When I switch between the main application or test suits, I have to do it manually using the dropdown near the green Run buton.